# Im trying to figure out why my table wont run through the summation function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to put a table through a summation function however the function doesn't consider any of the values inside as a number

I've tried changing how the table is set and what values go through but I have yet to accomplish my goal

```js
class Vector2{
    constructor(x, y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}

function Sum(a, start, end){
    let s = 0;
    for(i = start; i <= end; i++){
        s += a[i];
    }
    return s;
}


const v1 = new Vector2(1, 2);
const v2 = new Vector2(-1, 1);
const v3 = new Vector2(-1, -1);
const v4 = new Vector2(1, -1);


var arrX = [v1, v2, v3, v4];


//var sx = Sum(arrX, 0, 3);
//var sy = Sum(arrY, 0, 3);

//var X = (1/arrX.length)*Sum(arrX, 0, 3);
//var Y = (1/arrY.length)*Sum(arrY, 0, 3);

//console.log(X, Y);

function init(){
    var x = [];
    var y = [];
    var cx = 0;
    var cy = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < arrX.length; i++){
        x[i] = arrX[i].x;
        console.log(Sum(x, 0, 3));
    }
}

init();
```

Comment: Why do you think `+` is defined on your objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this block, you're summing the array each time you add an item to it.

```
for(i = 0; i < arrX.length; i++){
    x[i] = arrX[i].x;
    console.log(Sum(x, 0, 3));
}
```

You should be summing the array after it's filled.

```
for(i = 0; i < arrX.length; i++){
    x[i] = arrX[i].x;
}
console.log(Sum(x, 0, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum individual attributes (such as `'x'`) of objects in an array, you should have that attribute as a parameter to the summation function. The following works:

```
const sumAttribute = (my_array,att) => my_array.reduce((a,c) => a+c[att],0);
```

The attribute would need to be passed as a string. For example:

```js
class Vector2{
    constructor(x, y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}

const sumAttribute = (my_array,att) => my_array.reduce((a,c) => a+c[att],0);

const v1 = new Vector2(1, 2);
const v2 = new Vector2(-1, 1);
const v3 = new Vector2(-1, -1);
const v4 = new Vector2(1, -1);


var arr = [v1, v2, v3, v4];

console.log(sumAttribute(arr,'x'));
console.log(sumAttribute(arr,'y'));
```